# Google Sheets "=QUERY()" JOIN ON or equitant

Tags: sql, arrays, google-maps, google-sheets, google-query-language

I have one large spreadsheet with names, addresses, phone numbers, emails, Etc. Some records have a second address for which I have a column named "Address 2" I was hopping to write a query that would give me an output with duplicate rows of which the only difference was the "Address 2" column would be in the main address Column.

Data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Status** | **Name** | **Address** | **Phone** | **Email** | **Address2** | **Hire Date** |
| **2** |  | **Joe Smith** | **123 Smith St** | 201 555 3099 | Joe@stackoverflow.com | **7th Avenue Sq** |  |
| **4** | Q | Jane Smith | 321 Not Smith St |  |  |  | 12/15/1980 |
| **5** |  | Robert Smith |  | 818 555 4321 | Robert@googlesheets.com |  | 12/13/1981 |

Looking for an  Query output to look like:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Status** | **Name** | **Address** | **Phone** | **Email** | **Hire Date** |
| **2** |  | **Joe Smith** | **123 Smith St** | 201 555 3099 | Joe@stackoverflow.com |  |
| **3** |  | **Joe Smith** | **7th Avenue Sq** | 201 555 3099 | Joe@stackoverflow.com |  |
| **4** | Q | Jane Smith | 321 Not Smith St |  |  | 12/15/1980 |
| **5** |  | Robert Smith |  | 818 555 4321 | Robert@googlesheets.com | 12/13/1981 |

I was trying something like: 
`=QUERY({Sheet1!$A2:$G,Sheet1!$B2:$B,Sheet1!$F2:$J },"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col7 JOIN Col6 ON Col2 = Col2")`
Which I think is more or less how it would be in SQL, but Google sheets doesn't have a join function.

Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most simple you can do is:

```
=QUERY({A1:E, G1:G; A2:B, F2:F, D2:E, G2:G}, "where Col3 is not null", )
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
You can stack data of the same length with `{}`,
this sample create 2 query function and stack them together.

```
=ArrayFormula(
LAMBDA(DATA_1,DATA_2,
 QUERY({DATA_1;DATA_2},"WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Col2",1)
)(
 QUERY({A1:G4},"SELECT "&JOIN(",","Col"&{1,2,3,4,5,7}),1),
 QUERY({A1:G4},"SELECT "&JOIN(",","Col"&{1,2,6,4,5,7})&" WHERE Col6 IS NOT NULL LABEL "&JOIN(",","Col"&{1,2,6,4,5,7}&"''"),1)
)
)
```